# recorded Audio file is not working in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

I am developing a web admin application and backend for IOS & android mobile apps.
I am recording audio from the web using `navigation.mediaDevices` api.

When I record audio from chrome and firefox and upload to the server then this recorded audio file is playing in android but not playing in ios app.

and when I record audio from safari then audio file played in ios & android

Note - I am statically serving audio file from server

below I have written code to record audio from web using browser `navigation.mediaDevices` api

```
import * as toast from "../Toast";

export default function recordAudio() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
          audioBitsPerSecond: 32000,
          // bitsPerSecond: 32000
          // mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=opus",
        });

        const audioChunks = [];

        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
          audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        function start() {
          mediaRecorder.start();
        }

        function pause() {
          mediaRecorder.pause();
        }

        function resume() {
          mediaRecorder.resume();
        }

        function stop() {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
              const audioName = "audio.mp3";

              const blobData = new Blob(audioChunks, {
                type: "audio/mpeg",
              });
              const audioFile = new File([blobData], audioName, {
                type: "audio/mpeg",
              });
              const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioFile);
              const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
              function play() {
                audio.play();
              }

              stream.getTracks()[0].stop();

              resolve({ audioFile, audioUrl, play, audioName });
            });

            mediaRecorder.stop();
          });
        }

        resolve({ start, stop, pause, resume });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.info(
          "To record Voice Messages, application needs access to your computer’s microphone. Click in the URL bar and set “Use the Microphone” to “Allow.” "
        );
      });
  });
}
```

Please feel free to send in your suggestions and solutions.
Thank you

Comment: what codec/format is the audio file (don't rely on the code, what does the browser actually send to the server)

Comment: @JaromandaX 

mimeType:"audio/webm; codecs=pcm"

Comment: when you try to playback, what mimetype and/or filename do you use ... not sure why you'd use `.mp3` for a file that is `audio/webm` with pcm encoding. Safari probably just chokes on the inconsistency of it all

Comment: Be sure you actually check the actual media type (MIME type) of the streams recorded from your various mobile devices. Safari / webkit -- the browser tech in iOS -- botched the implementation of MediaRecorder pretty badly compared to Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Ios does not support playing webm files at this time. You have to convert them to something shared like mp3. I’ve tried a million times myself. There are docs that reference PCM and codecs that lead you to believe it should but it doesn’t when you try it out.