Audio tag html doesn't play sound when clicked on IOS
I'm in Blazor server and when I click on my audio tag, it doesn't play any sound. But when I click it on Android or on Windows PC, it works well.
This is my code:
@if (Question.Parcours.Type == Constants.TypeLanguage)
{
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
        @if (Question.AudioFilePath != null)
        {
            <audio class="m-1" controls>
                <source src="./@FolderAudioFile/@Question.AudioFilePath" type="audio/mp3">
                Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'élément audio.
            </audio>
        }

        @if (Managing)
        {
            @if (recording)
            {
                <h2 class="m-1 alert-danger">En cours d'enregistrement...</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-3" disabled="@DisableStopRecoredingBtn" @onclick="StopRecording">
                    <i class="bi bi-mic-mute-fill"></i> Arrêter d'enregistrer l'audio
                </button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3" @onclick="StartRecording">
                    <i class="bi bi-mic-fill"></i> Commencer à enregistrer l'audio
                </button>
            }
        }
    </div>
    @if (ErrorMessage != null)
    {
        <span class="alert-danger">@ErrorMessage</span>
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public QuestionDto Question { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Managing { get; set; } = true;
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
    private byte[] audioBytes;
    private bool recording = false;
    private bool DisableStopRecoredingBtn { get; set; } = false;
    private string AudioDirectory = Path.Combine("wwwroot", FolderAudioFile);
    private string? ErrorMessage { get; set; } = null;
    private string MessagePermissionDenied = "Vous devez permettre à l'application d'accéder à votre micro!";

    private async Task StartRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            ErrorMessage = null;
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("startRecording");
            recording = true;
            StateHasChanged();

            await Task.Delay(60000);

            if (recording)
            {
                await StopRecording();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = MessagePermissionDenied;
        }
    }

    private async Task StopRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            DisableStopRecoredingBtn = true;

            audioBytes = await JS.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("stopRecording");

            const int maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

            if (audioBytes.Length > maxFileSize)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Le fichier est trop gros, le maximum est de 5 MB.";
                return;
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(AudioDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AudioDirectory);
            }

            var randomFileName = $"P{Question.ParcoursId}-Q{Question.Id}-{Path.GetRandomFileName()}.mp3";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(AudioDirectory, randomFileName);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, audioBytes);

            Question.AudioFilePath = randomFileName;

            recording = false;
            DisableStopRecoredingBtn = false;

            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = MessagePermissionDenied;
        }
    }
}

So for playing the sound with the audio tag it doesn't work. Can you help me? Strangely, when I record on IOS I can click the audio and it plays the sound well. It seems that the get file doesn't work? When I register I can heard the sound. But if I come back and the audio file is not here and need to be loaded, this doesn't work on ios. Do I do wrongly my convertion for Ios?
this is the javascript recorder:
let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];

function logToConsole(message)
{
    console.log(message);
}

async function startRecording() {
    audioChunks = [];
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.start();
}

function stopRecording() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
            const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
            const arrayBuffer = await audioBlob.arrayBuffer();
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            resolve(byteArray);
        };
        mediaRecorder.stop();
    });
}


This kind of problem has been there since the beginning.  Mobile devices have a higher bar for allowing control of device functionality, like media playback or access to the microphone.

What do you suggest?

This is the rule for mobile problems like this-- only if you have an actual physical click on the screen, then it will accept that the client really wants to load / playback data via JavaScript.  This is by design, to protect developers from wasting mobile data by autoplaying ads etc.  It also explains why recording and playing back works, as it is initiated with a button click, whereas your loaded audio doesn't work as it is not.
There are various levels you can try to get past this:

Don't make your <audio> render conditionally.  Obviously, a careful OS will not let you just create and play a new sound object whenever you want.  Instead, render it always without the @if condition, starting with a 1-second silent audio file, and change the audio source later without creating a new <audio> object.  Maybe (maybe!) this will be enough.
Use JavaScript to start playing the audio off of any other button, then immediately pause it again.  Once you've done this, you should be able to resume playback at any time later, even if you change the audio source (which you will definitely do).  This "catching a click" technique is very useful to understand and use for mobile devices.

Unfortunately, I can't test code for an Apple product, since I refuse ever to buy one again.  But hopefully now you have a better understanding of WHY things mysteriously refuse to play or record on Apple devices.
Also, my understanding was that new Apple OS versions are more generous with media control.  Do you have an older product?  If so, you might want to check a new device to see if it's a version issue.

I changed my code, but this is not working. I've try to get rid of the IF but doesn't work. I noticed one thing: When I put in the src this "./sounds/CorrectAnswer.mp3", the sound play on iphone. But if I use my mp3 file that was recorded, this is not playing for a reason that I cannot determine. I lose my mind on this...

But what is crazy is that if I record the audio with a Iphone, the audio will work. I'm out of me haha

"mp3 that was recorded."  Neither Android nor iPhone so far as I know directly records in mp3.  I use a JS library to convert to mp3 on client side so I don't bog down my server.  What, exactly, are you doing to record to mp3?

I've put the code in my post. What I noticed is when I record on IOS, the audio will work on IOS. But if I record on my Windows PC, the audio will not work on IOS

It's like this post as the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382458/recorded-audio-file-is-not-working-in-ios

Okay, a few things.  (1) All your audio processing should be done with pure javascript or a WASM component.  You don't want to have to process who-knows-how-much sound data on your expensive Microsft VM (or whatever).  (2)  You are not, in fact, converting the data to a usable format before saving it.  As far as any browser is concerned your, "audio.mp3" or whatever is just random bytes.
